# Codeigniter Email Class is not working

Tags: html, codeigniter, email

I am trying Codeigniter Email Class but it is not working or May be, I am making mistakes with configuration or something else. please fix it and inform me someone what I should do. I am having a problem with the codeigniter email class.

This is the screenshot after sending the form data to the controller.

[image: This is the screenshot after sending the form data to the controller]

View:

```
                <h4>Send Your Feedback</h4>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url('front/feedBack') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name<span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" name="senderName" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Phone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone no<span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" name="senderPhone" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone no">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email<span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" name="senderEmail" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Subject" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" name="senderSubject" class="form-control" id="Subject" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Message" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Message<span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <textarea name="senderMsg" class="form-control" id="Message" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function feedBack()
{
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

    $config['smtp_host'] = 'host8.registrar-servers.com';

    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';

    $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@dewbn.com';

    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'myPass';

    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

    $config['crlf'] = '\r\n';      //should be "\r\n"
    $config['newline'] = '\r\n';   //should be "\r\n"

    $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

    $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not

    $this->email->initialize($config);



    $senderName = $this->input->post('senderName');
    $senderPhone = $this->input->post('senderPhone');
    $senderEmail = $this->input->post('senderEmail');
    $senderSubject = $this->input->post('senderSubject');
    $senderMsg = $this->input->post('senderMsg');

    $this->email->from($senderEmail, $senderName);
    $this->email->to('bablukpik@gmail.com');


    $this->email->subject($senderSubject);

    $this->email->message($senderMsg);

    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo "Success!";
        //return true;
    } else {
        echo "Failure!";
        //return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$config = Array(
                'protocol' =>  'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'test1@gmail.com',
                'smtp_port' =>  2525,
                'smtp_user' => 'gmailusername',
                'smtp_pass' => 'password',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
            );
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

    $THIS->email->initialize($config);
    $THIS->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $body = str_replace(array('{LOGO_IMAGE}'),array($logo_image),$body);

    $body.= email_footer();
    $body = '<div style="width:700px;float:left;">'.$body.'</div>';
    if (!empty($from))
    {
        $from_name = !empty($from_name) ? $from_name : SITE_NAME;
        $from = !empty($from) ? $from : 'noreply@test.com';        
        $THIS->email->from($from, $from_name);
    }
    else
    {
        $THIS->email->from('noreply@test.com', $from_name);
    }
    if (!empty($to))
    {
        $THIS->email->to($to);
    }
    if (!empty($cc))
    {
        $THIS->email->cc($cc);
    }
    if (!empty($bcc))
    {
        $THIS->email->cc($bcc);
    }
    $THIS->email->subject($subject);
    $THIS->email->message($body);

    if (!empty($attachment))
    {
        if (is_array($attachment))
        {
            foreach ($attachment as $val) 
            {
                $THIS->email->attach($val);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $THIS->email->attach($val);
        }
    }

    if ($THIS->email->send())
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        echo $THIS->email->print_debugger();
        exit;
    }
```

Mark it accepted if it works.